# @Inject services in other service - Nest can't resolve dependencies

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, dao, nestjs

I'm trying to @Inject two services into a NestJS service and am getting

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MainServiceImpl (?,
>   Symbol(MainDao)). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is
>   available in the MainModule context

Here is the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MainServiceImpl implements MainService {

    constructor(
        @Inject(TYPES.PublishSubscriptionService) private publishSubscriptionService: PublishSubscriptionService,
        @Inject(TYPES.MainDao) private mainDao: MainDao
    ) {}
```

Now if I switch the order, it's always the second injected service that gets the error.

TYPES is an object of [Symbols](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#non-class-based-provider-tokens)

```
const TYPES = {
    PublishSubscriptionService: Symbol('PublishSubscriptionService'),
    MainDao: Symbol('MainDao'),
};
export default TYPES;
```

Here is the index.ts which is using barreling

```
// start:ng42.barrel
export * from './main.dao.mongo-impl';
export * from './main.dao';
export * from './main';
export * from './main.schema';
export * from './main.service.impl';
export * from './main.service';
// end:ng42.barrel
```

What am I missing?

[Closed NestJS issue with no resolution](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/825)
[NestJS doc on @Global modules](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#global-modules)

Comment: Did you create your custom provider to also use Symbols? And if so, is that custom provider in the same context as the module of the service that you are currently trying to work with?

Comment: This sounds like it could be an index.ts issue.  Are you using barrel files?  If so, you'll need to show more of your code to help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: That is interesting @raychz, I've added the index file for this module but am not able to understand how it could be involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for sure without seeing your `MainServieImplModule` or whatever the module that contains this service is called, but if I had to guess, you are not declaring your `providers` to Nest correctly for these two services. You'll need to create a custom provider like so

```
@Module({
  provides: [
    {
      provide: TYPES.PublishSubscriptionService,
      useClass: PublishSubscriptionService,
    },
    {
      provide: TYPES.MainDao,
      useClass: MainDao
    },
    MainServiceImpl
  ]
})
export class MainServiceImplModule {}
```

If however, those providers are part of a different module you will need to make sure that the providers are custom (as above), but are also exported so they can be imported and used in a different module. Without seeing more of your code, the question is not possible to answer, but I think this should give you the direction you need. If not, please edit your question and add more information.

Comment: I believe the final issue at play is that the original Node project uses deep abstraction. Converting to Nest breaks that and needs to be rebuilt first. MainDao refers to interface only until it is repointed to an actual construct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what TYPES is, you can use @Inject(PublishSubscriptionService) or you can use simply:

```
constructor(
        private publishSubscriptionService: PublishSubscriptionService,
        private mainDao: MainDao
) {}
```